# How to set same image for iPhone and iPad during Universal app development?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

- I have searched a lot on this topic and now I am confused. According to them for iPhone and iPad we have different conventions like (`image~iphone.png ,image@2x~ipad.png`).
- My question I have to import all images in the assets folder for **iPhone** mentioned below.

> image@2x~iphone.png
>
> image@2x.png
>
> image~iphone.png
>
> image.png

And same for the **iPad** also

> image@2x~ipad.png*
>
> image@2x.png*
>
> image~ipad.png
>
> image.png

There is a duplicate image in iPhone and iPad assets.Please let me know the best way to deal with the same image used for iPhone and iPad.

Also, we need to import @3x images for iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 0):

assets folder are build over app slicing and app thinning cocepts means all images which are 1x 2x and 3x would be included in your bundle but when user download your app from app store only images which suit the particular device downloaded from the apple server so you don't need to be worry about app size. no you don't need 1x 2x 3x images  for iPhone and iPad. You can do it with single image set for example 2x is best in your case just include 2x images for all your device included iPad and iPhone.